# Replace Xcode Project with Swift Package while keeping same GitHub repo?

Tags: xcode, git, swift-package-manager

I'm currently refactoring my Xcode project into a Swift Package with multiple modules, which I combine with a lightweight Xcode project using an XCWorkspace (kind of like Pointfree's [isowords](https://github.com/pointfreeco/isowords)). Right now, my Xcode project is hosted on a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nikitamounier/tapit-app). However, with this refactoring, it's the Swift Package which will be hosted on GitHub.

Can I replace my Xcode project with the Swift Package on the repo, without losing all my history? Will the history of files inside my Xcode project still show up?

Comment: If you're ever worried about a git operation destroying your commit history (reasonable, that would be scary!), here's something you can do. If you `git clone` your git repository to a new folder on your computer, the entire commit history will be stored in a hidden `.git` directory. Then, you can do your operation with the safety of having a backup. If something goes wrong, you can `git push --force` from your backup, and the commit history on GitHub will be replaced by the commit history from your backup. https://www.datree.io/resources/git-push-force

Comment: Thank you! I did my big move, and all went well. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will be fine. Even if you delete every single file in your git repository and push it, your entire commit history will still be there. Feel free to replace your project with a package!

Comment: This gave me the confidence to make my big move, which I did – and all went swimmingly. Thanks a lot